# How do you pass a template name to a method?

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say I have two template functions for iterating through a container:

```
template <typename I, typename C>
It Prev(I i, const C& c) noexcept {
    Expects(i != c.end());
    if (i == c.begin()) return c.end();
    return i - 1;
}
```

and

```
template <typename I, typename C>
It Next(I i, const C& c) noexcept {
    Expects(i != c.end());
    return i + 1;
}
```

And a class with a GetNextElement and GetPrevElement that use these templates:

```
struct MyClass {
  std::vector<int> elements;

  int* GetNextElement(std::vector<int>::iterator i) {
    auto next = Next(i, elements);
    if (next == elements.end()) return nullptr;
    return &*it;
  }
  int* GetPrevElement(std::vector<int>::iterator i) {
    auto prev = Prev(i, elements);
    if (prev == elements.end()) return nullptr;
    return &*it;
  }
};
```

These two methods do the same thing, except for calling a different template. How do I turn these into a single member function that might be called like

```
MyClass mc;
// ...
auto it = mc.elements.begin();
auto next = mc.GetElement<Next>(it);
// Or maybe mc.GetElement(it, Next);
```

Comment: `Next` and `Prev` expect a reference to the container associated with the iterator. `GetElement` is unaware of the container. Since you seem to be using `std::vector::iterator`s I don't see how to achieve this. You will either need to pass the container to `GetElement` or drop that requirement from `Next` and `Prev`.

Comment: You have not defined what `Expects` is. You use `It` as the return type type for `Prev` and `Next`, but it's indeclared. It looks like you meant to use the type `I`.

Comment: I may have simplified too much in my example and exposed things that the caller would be unaware of. The caller doesn't know how the elements are stored in the class. He just knows that he can get an identifier to an element, and given that he can call "GetNextElement" or "GetPrevElement". Since these two methods are almost exactly alike, I'd like to be able to have a single method and have the caller specify whether it should use the Next or Prev template function to get the desired element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is greatly simplified if you can wrap your functions in `struct`.

```
struct Prev
{
    template <typename I, typename C>
    I operator()(I i, const C& c) noexcept {
        Expects(i != c.end());
        if (i == c.begin()) return c.end();
        return i - 1;
    }
};

struct Next
{
    template <typename I, typename C>
    I operator()(I i, const C& c) noexcept {
        Expects(i != c.end());
        return i + 1;
    }
};
```

You can then simply pass them as template arguments.

```
struct MyClass 
{
public:
    auto begin() { return elements.begin(); }
    auto end() { return elements.end(); }

    template<typename T, typename I>
    I GetElement(I iter)
    {
        return T()(iter, this->elements);
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> elements;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    auto it = mc.begin();
    auto next = mc.GetElement<Next>(it);
    auto prev = mc.GetElement<Prev>(it);
}
```

Comment: The caller would not have access to mc.elements itself (it's private), so a free function would not help. I only exposed it to simplify the example. I want the caller to be able to tell the method to use Next or Prev, but not know what types are used to instantiate it.

Comment: In your example `GetElement<Next>` has no way of knowing which instance of `mc` or `mc.element` to use. Did you want `GetElement<T>` to be a member method of `MyClass`?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that. Yes, GetElement was intended to be a member, replacing the two GetPrevElement and GetNextElement methods. I fixed the typo. Sorry. So the edit doesn't really address the problem, since it's calling the two members instead of replacing them.

Comment: @Kian Edited again.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define OINVOKE(...) __VA_ARGS__(decltype(args)(args)...)
#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) [](auto&&...args)\
    noexcept(noexcept(OINVOKE(__VA_ARGS__)))\
    ->decltype(OINVOKE(__VA_ARGS__))\
    { return OINVOKE(__VA_ARGS__); }

auto fNext=OVERLOADS_OF(Next);
auto fPrev=OVERLOADS_OF(Prev);
```

Then:

```
template<auto* pf>
int* GetElement(std::vector<int>::iterator i) {
  auto next = (*pf)(i, elements);
  if (next == elements.end()) return nullptr;
  return &*it;
}
auto it = mc.elements.begin();
auto next = GetElement<&fNext>(it);
```

requires C++17.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
template <std::vector<int>::iterator (*FOO)(std::vector<int>::iterator, const std::vector<int>&)>
std::vector<int>::iterator GetElement(std::vector<int>::iterator i)
{
     return FOO(i, elements);
}
```